# Configuration::get() returning empty value in Controller of PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using PrestaShop 1.6.1.0

I have a field in my module supporting different languages, the `postProcess()` looks like this:

```php
protected function postProcess()
{

  $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
  $values = array();

  foreach ($languages as $lang)
  {
    $values['CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT'][$lang['id_lang']] = Tools::getValue('CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT_'.$lang['id_lang']);
  }
  Configuration::updateValue('CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT', $values['CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT'], true);
  return $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('The settings have been updated.'));
}
```

**Problem:**

When I try to get this configuration variable value in a custom controller (path: `/controllers/front/CustomPageController.php`) like shown below, it is not fetching any results:

```php
$headtxt = Configuration::get('CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT');
print_r($headtxt);
exit;
```

It is not printing anything. I want to fetch this value in a controller, but it does not work and returns an empty string.

Site is using PrestaShop 1.6.1.0 and I tried many codes available. Am I missing something?

I am using this code in new controller created by me for custom page:

```php
$headtxt = Configuration::get('CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT');
print_r($headtxt);
exit;
```

I expect to output results of configuration variable which saved by the `postProcess()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Ankur and Welcome to SO!

In your `postProcess()` method, you are saving this Configuration value as a multilingual value.

However, while calling the `Configuration::get()` static method, it seems to me you forgot to mention the language ID, here's the function prototype:

```
public static function get($key, $idLang = null, $idShopGroup = null, $idShop = null, $default = false)
```

**This should work:**

```
$id_lang = (int)$this->context->cookie->id_lang
$headtxt = Configuration::get('CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT', $id_lang);
print_r($headtxt);
exit;﻿
```

Comment: HI @Bruno, Thanks for replying me. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks. it is working now. I have one other question, Prestashop having multistore.

Comment: I’m glad this is resolved :-) You can mark this answer as accepted. Please post a new separate question for the other topic. Thank you

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks. it is working now. I have one other question, Prestashop having multistore.  So each store have different language. My question is while saving this field in db by ```Configuration::updateValue``` in ```postProcess``` function we need to save any shop id reference? Or Prestashop will automatically manage it? Also after saving it, How to get value for other store via ```Configuration::get``` ? Please let me know. I searched but didnt find anything.

Comment: This is handled automatically using the context (current shop id) however you can also pass the Shop ID as a parameter if you’d like

Comment: HI Bruno, sorry my question is related to same code, So I am continuing on this thread.  I tried to get value by this code 

```$id_lang = (int)$this->context->cookie->id_lang;
$id_shop = (int)$this->context->cookie->id_shop;
$headtxt = Configuration::get('CUSTOMPAGECONFIGURATION_HEADING_TEXT', $id_lang, $id_shop );
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($headtxt); 
exit;``` 

But not working. I checked in admin and France Multistore have value for this text box. Am I doing something wrong?